# stop scrolling tableview while animating

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

How to stop table which scrolling immediately when I press a button.

I have tried this way.

```
 -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
             if([mTableview isDecelerating]) {
                  isTableScrolling = YES;
   }
 }



-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView                                           
{
    if(isTableScrolling)
     {

    [mTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [mTableView setDecelerationRate:0];
      }

}
```

But table stop's scrolling after some delay.

Answer (score 6):

Try [self setContentOffset:self.contentOffset animated:NO]

Comment: As a note; using self.contentOffset = self.contentOffset is not good enough. You must use the above suggestion. In my case I needed to use [self.tableView setContentOffset:self.tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];